# Some windows are missing the top part of the screen

Tags: windows-10, graphics, bug

[image]

Sometimes when I enter full-screen, some of my windows miss the top inch and a half of the monitor. The picture does not really show it very well, but the "cut off" section is just a solid white bar.

I have tried following the steps in [this forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/black-bar-on-top-of-screen-with-random/1282761a-cf46-490d-b1db-f686898d9f23), and it resolved the problem for a whopping 15 minutes after restart.

How do I fix this permanently?

Comment: Try updating all your drivers, especially Video and perhaps BIOS.  Use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App.

Comment: Is it always the same windows that get truncated? If yes, which products do that?

Comment: @harrymc it is not, it is usually just one monitor, not both with this issue (Though which on is the bad monitor changes), and then it will usually be the browsers, and sometimes discord.

Comment: Here's one fix from learn.microsoft.com. This is about Teams, but it might work with other applications as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/690105/blank-bar-at-top-of-teams-page-when-fully-expanded